# How to set up Stripe as the default payment option and always display it expanded in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm trying to set up Stripe as the first payment option in Magento 2 and I want it to always appear expanded, without requiring the user to click on the radio button to reveal it. Currently, when I enter the checkout process, I have to click on the radio button to expand the payment options and select Stripe.
I have installed the Stripe payment module in Magento 2 and have configured it correctly. However, I cannot find a way to set Stripe as the default payment option and always display it expanded.

Is there any specific configuration I need to make in Magento 2 to achieve this? Or is it necessary to modify the code to customize this functionality?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide clear instructions on how to achieve this goal. Thank you!

I have installed the Stripe payment module in Magento 2 and configured it according to the provided documentation. I expected that by enabling Stripe as the first payment option and setting it to "Always Expanded" in the configuration, it would appear expanded by default during the checkout process.
However, even after making these changes, Stripe still appeared collapsed initially, requiring the user to manually click on the radio button to expand the payment options and select Stripe. This behavior did not match my expectation of having Stripe always displayed and expanded.

I also reviewed the Magento 2 documentation and explored various configuration settings related to payment options, but I couldn't find a specific option to achieve the desired behavior.

I'm looking for guidance on how to make Stripe the default payment option and have it always displayed in an expanded state during the checkout process.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add code to achieve this

`requirejs-config.js` file

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': {
                'Company_Vendor/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

checkout-data-resolver.js file

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method'
], function(
    paymentService,
    checkoutData,
    selectPaymentMethodAction
) {
    'use strict';

    return function(checkoutDataResolver) {
        checkoutDataResolver.resolvePaymentMethod = function() {
            var availablePaymentMethods = paymentService.getAvailablePaymentMethods(),
                selectedPaymentMethod = checkoutData.getSelectedPaymentMethod(),
                paymentMethod = selectedPaymentMethod ? selectedPaymentMethod : "stripe_payment_method";

            if (availablePaymentMethods.length > 0) {
                availablePaymentMethods.some(function (payment) {
                    if (payment.method == paymentMethod) {
                        selectPaymentMethodAction(payment);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        return checkoutDataResolver;
    };
});
```

Comment: but this is a custom module?